# Trouble getting first PhoneGap Android app to run

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I'm a new user of PhoneGap.  My platform is Windows 7 64 bit.  I've followed the instructions on the Cordova site and have Node & PhoneGap installed.  I already have Eclipse and the ADT installed from my previous work with developing Android apps with Java.

Following the steps at http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html I'm half way through step 4.  I've successfully created the my skeletal hello world PhoneGap app.  How exactly do I make an Eclipse project out of it however?  The generated files do not seen to include the standard Eclipse .project file.  It is not clear from the instructions which exact "new project" menu option to choose.

Thanks if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating cordova project through command line, I'm assuming you have added platform using `cordova platform add android`

Then to load project into eclipse, do this

> Eclipse> file > import >Android >Existing acdroid code ..... > Root
>   directory (Browse button...... Browse to this folder
>   [yourcordovaproject-platforms-android] select this android folder)>
>   Check both your project name & cordovaLib > Finish

Comment: Yes I had skipped the add android platform step.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had jumped ahead to the "create Android app." step without having run the "cordova platform add android" step first.  I ran the add android step, and that did generate the Eclipse project files I needed.